# Batch replace with special characters not working

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to d a simple batch replace of doublequotes to singlequotes.
The teststring must containg special characters, at most: `"<LF>"`
I cannot replace the double quotes there, as the batch just exists with `Syntaxerror`. Do you know why, or how to overcome this?

```
SET TEST="<LF>","<HT>"
SET modified=%TEST:"='%  <-- Syntaxerror
ECHO %modified%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use delayed expansion:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET TEST="<LF>","<HT>"
SET modified=!TEST:"='!  <-- Syntaxerror
ECHO !modified!
```

As [Mr Fuzzy Button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15944691/73070) notes, the problem is that the shell interprets `<` and `>` as redirection. Delayed expansion (using `!` instead of `%`) expands variables *after* parsing and thus does not affect redirection.

You can solve the `SET` without delayed expansion by enclosing the argument in quotes:

```
SET "modified=!TEST:"='!"
```

But the `ECHO` would still be problematic, then.

Comment: This is great and probably best, as I only have to make tiny modifications to my existing files.

Comment: So am I right I always have to use `!modified!` instead `%modified%` wherever this variable is used? Or can I somehow "transform" it back to a variable that can be again used with `%` so that I would not have to change other code?

Comment: Yes, and it must be when delayed expansion is enabled (i.e. from that `setlocal` until its matching `endlocal` or the end of execution). Otherwise you'll only get `!modified!` instead of the value. It still is a normal variable. The only thing that changed is the semantics of when it is expanded to its value. Delayed expansion works more akin to how variables work in other programming languages. If you use `%modified%` it will work but as long as you'll have things like `<` or `>` in there it will mess things up unless you quote properly. And `echo` cannot be quoted.

Answer (score 1):

While delayed expansion is a good thing, it's not necessary to answer this question. There are also times when setlocal isn't available. I ran into one.

In the windows shell, string matching for quotes works on outermost match pairs (in most cases, but not all), not innermost.

```
SET TEST="<LF>","<HT>"
echo %TEST%
SET "modified=%TEST:"='%"
echo.|set /p "___=%modified%"
```

Workaround: If echo can't print something, set can. Go figure.

Comment: I like your answer but you need to escape the character you want to replace too in order to print the string properly: `set modified=!TEST:^&=^^^&!` . I was trying ampersand escaping though

Answer (score 0):

This works for me...

```
SET TEST="LF","HT"
echo %TEST%
SET modified=%TEST:"='%
ECHO %modified%
```

The problem lies in your `<`s and `>`s being interpreted as input/output pipes in the `Echo`

Comment: You got me wrong. the teststring is a fixed(!) string I want to replace. I cannot change the teststring, and thus cannot remove the < > chars.